# How is emdeding of cython syntax inside python syntax implemented?

Tags: syntax, frontend, cython, embedded-language

Looking on [simple example of cython code](http://nealhughes.net/cython1/) I wonder if CPython interpreter needed some hard-coded hacks to understand cython syntax (e.g. `cdef int N`) or if it is implemented using some concepts of standard python syntax (e.g. functions, classes, operators etc.)

I mean, I can roughly imagine how the cython backend can be implemented (c-code generation, compilation etc.), but I don't understand how the frontend syntax can be integrated within standard python interpreter without touching the python interpteter itself (i.e. without extending python language beyond standard).

#### What is `cdef` ?

In other words, what `cdef` actually is? Is it a function, operator, or some new keyword? I would understand `N = cedef(int)` - that would create instance of some class derived from `int`. But written like that, I don't see how these 3 tokens even interact (1 `cdef`, 2 `int`, 3 `N`) ?

#### Does the `for`-loop actually iterate?

if you write code like this:

```
cdef int    i,N = 1000000
cdef double f   = 0

for i in xrange(N):
     f += (i*i)
print f
```

The loop `for i in xrange(N):` is normal python loop. What prevents python interpreter to uselessly iterate 1000000 iterations before cython compile it into to C-code?

**Does it work something like this:**

`N` is an instance of some `class cdef`. `xrange` call `N.__int__()` which returns `1`, passing the loop only once. The expression `f += (i*i)` contains only `cdef` objects, so cython can redefine `__add_()`, `__set__()`, `__get__()` functions in a way that generate C-code for `f+=(i*i)`

But then I still don't see how the construct `for i in xrange()` is send to cython, to generate C code from it.

Anyway, it seems quite complicated and fragiel, so perhaps it must be otherwise

Comment: There is no need to speculate: just take a look at the generated C-code.

Comment: And python interpreter will not see the cython code (e.g. cdef), as it will become a c-extension when built.

Comment: I don't care how the generated c-code looks like. I care how CPython parse cython-decorated code.

Comment: aha, you are perhaps rigth, the the `.pyx` files are not parsed by CPython, Cython has it's own parser ... right? ... I was asking because I wanted to abuse python interpreter to generate different language.